# How to convert everything over to csv?

Tags: python, csv

I wasn't sure how to ask this question, so hopefully the title isn't confusing. I am creating an email list program which holds stored information in a list. There is an "add data" option in the command line where you are able to append information to the list using user input. When I append information, the program only holds the information until it is restarted. When the program restarts, the information isn't there anymore. I was told that using a "csv file" that loads whenever the program starts up is how I would keep the information persistent across multiple runs. Obviously the code I'm using is an example so I'm not giving out everyones information, but is there anyway I can use a csv file to import all of this information without needing to change the code much? My program is almost finished, just need to figure out how to write the rest of the code in a way where information is stored persistently and isn't deleted when I restart the program.

```
class Emails:
    def __init__(self, name, location, email):
        self.name = name
        self.location = location
        self.email = email


fans = [Emails('james franco', 'california', 'jamesfranco@gmail.com'),
        Emails('john cena', 'california', 'johncena@hotmail.com')
        ]


def append_input():
    input_name = input('Add Name: ')
    input_location = input('Add Location: ')
    input_email = input('Add Email: ')
    fans.append(Emails(input_name, input_location, input_email))


def all_data():
    for fan in fans:
        print(fan.name + '\n')
        print(fan.location + '\n')
        print(fan.email + '\n________________')



while True: 
    start_search = input("What would you like to search?(Name/Location/Email/All Data/Add Data): ")
    if start_search == "Add Data":
        append_input()
    if start_search == "All Data":
        all_data()
```

Answer (score 0):

To read data from a csv, define this function in your program:

```
def read_from_csv():
    fans = []
    with open('fans.csv', newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.writer(f)
        # Skip the header row.
        next(reader)
        for row in reader:
            fan = Emails(*row)
            fans.append(fan)
    return fan
```

and instead of

```
fans = [Emails('james franco', 'california', 'jamesfranco@gmail.com'),
        Emails('john cena', 'california', 'johncena@hotmail.com')
        ]
```

do

```
fans = read_from_csv()
```

To save the data, define this function in your program

```
def write_to_csv(fans):
    with open('fans.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(['name', 'location', 'email'])
        for fan in fans:
            writer.writerow([fan.name, fan.location, fan.email])
    return
```

and do

```
write_to_csv(fans)
```

just before your program completes.

See the docs for the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html) in the standard library for more information about processing csv files in Python.